# Multiple traits uses same base trait at the same time

Tags: php, traits

Okay say the following straits are given:

```
trait Base
{
    public function doSomething()
    {
        // Do fancy stuff needed in other traits
    }
}

trait A
{
    use Base;

    public function foo()
    {
        // Do something
    }
}


trait B
{
    use Base;

    public function bar()
    {
        // Do something else
    }
}
```

and I like to implement a class now which uses both traits `A` and `B`:

```
class MyClass
{
    use A, B;
}
```

PHP tells me it can't redefine function `doSomething()`. What's the reason PHP is not able to detect that `A` and `B` share one and the same trait and don't copy it twice into `MyClass` (is it a bug or a feature preventing me from writing unclean code)?

Is there a better solution for my problem then this workaround with which I ended up:

```
trait Base
{
    public function doSomething()
    {
        // Do fancy stuff needed in other traits
    }
}

trait A
{
    abstract function doSomething();

    public function foo()
    {
        // Do something
    }
}


trait B
{
    abstract function doSomething();

    public function bar()
    {
        // Do something else
    }
}
```

And then my class:

```
class MyClass
{
    use Base, A, B;
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can resolve this conflict with "insteadof" like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    use A, B {
        A::doSomething insteadof B;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
For more traits resolving conflicts can look like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    use A, B, C, D {
        A::doSomething insteadof B, C, D;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. So I would have to write this for each trait once? Like when I have traits `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` I have to write this three times? This looks for me like a "workaround" to somehow...

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER No, just add them all separated by comma: `use A, B, C, D {
        A::doSomething insteadof B, C, D;
    }`

Comment: I think then I stay with my initial solution. This seems to me clearer then the `insteadof` solution. Because poeple which use the traits `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` can also instead of using the `Base` trait implement the `doSomething()` function directly in their class (if needed). Thx anyway. If there nobody will come up with another solution I'm going to accept this one.

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER Glad I could help. Members from the current class override Trait methods. With `insteadof` you can choose from what trait the method will be called in class - for me it is clear. But, ofcourse, choose whatever you preffer.

Answer (score 3):

This has been fixed in PHP 7.3:

```php
trait A
{
    public function a(){}
}

trait B
{
    use A;
}

trait C
{
    use A;
}

class D
{
    use B, C;
}
```

Results:

```
PHP 7.3+ Fine
PHP ^5|^7.2: Fatal error: Trait method a has not been applied, because there are collisions with other trait methods on D in /in/Z5GTo on line 18
```

- https://3v4l.org/Z5GTo
- https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63911
- https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-7.php#7.3.0 *(Fixed bug #63911 (identical trait methods raise errors during composition)*

Props to @Grzegorz that posted the link to the PHP bug, to an answer, but got deleted by vote. I tried to re-open it but couldn't.

Comment: Tried it on PHP 8 and it worked.   Looked for validation on SO, and the only confirmation I found was your post.  Thanks.